# Using RANKX with a YTD Measure does not rank correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the Cumulative Purchases by YTD. The first step is to rank the items by Cost Amount, but when I try to rank by the [_YTD Cost] measure, the numbers I get do not make sense (skipped numbers, duplicated).

[[image]]

I had 3 slicers: Month, Year and to select Month/YTD measures. Since with the Month calculation I have no problems, I removed the interaction with the Month/YTD slicer and I placed only YTD measures on the table:

```
Total Purchase Cost = SUM ( Purchases[Amount] )

_YTD Cost = TOTALYTD([Total Purchase Cost], 'dim-calendar'[Date])

_RANK YTD = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Purchases), [_YTD Cost])
```

Notes:

1. I pulled the item from the Item table
2. The Purchase table is linked to the Date table by Purchase Date

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a small scale representative data here [how to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) and help us in helping you swiftly?

Comment: If you want to rank Items, then rank Items, not Purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100 % sure on your data model, but try changing your RANKX(ALLSELECTED(***) to reference the Item-column. Like this:

```
RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Item'[Item]), [_YTD Cost])
```

Comment: Thanks fro the replies. One question, though. How come the documentation states that the first parameter to RANKX has to be a table [RANKX(<table>, <expression>, <value>, <order>, <ties>)] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax)?